# Obtaining value within the function for use outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I am using two datetimepicker Bootstrap, the first is startDate, and the second is enddate, The problem is that i should pick the startdate, and in the enddate automaticlly to be minimum date(the date i select in startdate). And in the datatimepicker of enddate maximum of date to be +7 days. Can you help me please?

I tried to get the date in the first datatimepicker called datatimepicker6 , and i did it but i dont know how to use in the enddate datatimepicker called datatimepicker7. Below is the code:

```
//these part is to pick the date and it work
$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function(e) {
    var drr = $('#datetimepicker6').data('date')
    alert(drr);
});
      $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss',

        keyBinds: {'delete': null}
      });

//I want to use that result as the minimum of this datatimepicker and to add +7 days as maximum

      $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss',
        //useCurrent: false,
      //maxDate: drr,
        keyBinds: {'delete': null},


        useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
      });
```

Comment: are you using this one? http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your onchange event it will works

```
            e.date.add(7, 'day'); 
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);
```

full code for onchange

```
 $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
         //var val = $('#datetimepicker6').data('date');     
        e.date.add(7, 'day'); 
    $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);     
   $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date);

                });                
            });
```

[check the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/vcrqmw2n/16/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but dont work for me, it shows an error at part : minDate

Comment: sorry it was my problem, it works thank you very much, also i want to ask you if i want to -7 days how can i change this e.date.add(7, 'day');

Comment: just give -7 it will works `e.date.add(-7, 'day');` or Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/vcrqmw2n/20/

Answer (score 2):

No need to carry variable into another function, you can just declare a variable inside the event, working [Fiddle](https://codepen.io/gopal280377/pen/BERpBZ).

```
$(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
                        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss',
                        keyBinds: {'delete': null}
                    });


                  $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss',
                    useCurrent: false,
                    keyBinds: {'delete': null},
                    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
                  });

                  $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function(e) {
                        var drr = $('#datetimepicker6').data('date');
                        var endDate = new Date(e.date);
                        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+7);
                        $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(drr);
                        $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(endDate);
                });
         });
```